# How to create a .vscode directory in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

Where to put the .vscode directory and how to create it in vscode using python? I need it to set some configurations on my project

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um71j.png)

Comment: Why do you want to create it? Wouldn't VSCode create it automatically for you? (Side note: please don't post images of text like code or errors or folder structure. See [ask].)

Comment: don't put your python source files in your virtual environment, read the VSC Python doc page on environments

Answer (score 0):

**Please do not create it manually.**

When you use the schema option of vscode to create a project, for example:

[image]

Vscode will automatically create this folder for you:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that. Thank you a lot. Ive been suffering for so long...